# Halogen Ace example throws a ReferenceError

Tags: ace-editor, purescript, halogen

I downloaded prescript-halogen-6.1.3 and I tried to run the Ace example. When I open the index.html file I get a ReferenceError in the browser:
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`

Comment: Looks like maybe you forgot to bundle?

Comment: The example uses bundling, but only for the PureScript code, not for any npm dependencies. I got it working by using rollup for the npm dependency bundling. I had to manually install ace-builds.